# Unable to marshal some_type*** from C to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, .net, marshalling

I need to use one specific method call from C#. DLL written on C.

```
vout_thread_t **pp_vout;
size_t i_vout;

if( input_Control( p_input, INPUT_GET_VOUTS, &pp_vout, &i_vout ) )
     return NULL;
```

method define in C header

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int input_Control( input_thread_t *, int i_query, ...  );
```

looks I need to define `vout_thread_t ***ppp_vout` or something like it.

`vout_thread_t` is a struct, I don't use any members of this, and can use IntPtr instead as a handle, to simplify code.

I've tried to use IntPtr[] but it's doesn't worked, result is not correct in array.

Comment: It's not an IntPtr array, it's a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Use struct VoidPtr { VoidPtr * ptr; } it supports unlimited size of pointer chain like ***, and convertible to C#

Comment: Thank you! Good suggestion.